# Gekko solver for optimizing function; Certain local minimum, but it will be found just on rare occasions

Tags: python, optimization, solver, gekko

```py
from gekko import GEKKO 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()  # initialize gekko

nt=200
m.time = np.linspace(0,1,nt)
# Variables
x1 = m.Var(value=20,lb=0,)
x2 = m.Var(value=0,lb=0,)
x3 = m.Var(value=0,lb=0,)

p = np.zeros(nt)  # mark final time point
p[-1] = 1.0

# optimize final time
tf = m.FV(value=0.7,lb=0.001,ub=100.0)
tf.STATUS = 1

# Equations
m.Equation(x1.dt() == -5*x1*tf)
m.Equation(x2.dt() == (5* x1 - 0.5*x2)*tf)
m.Equation(x3.dt() == 0.5*x2*tf)


#Minifunc
#m.Minimize(tf)
m.Maximize(x2)

#options
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.SOLVER = 3 #IPOPT optimizer
m.options.RTOL = 1E-8
m.options.OTOL = 1E-8
m.options.NODES = 5
m.solve(disp=True,debug=1)

print('Final Time: ' + str(tf.value[0]))
#Plotting stuff 
tm = np.linspace(0,tf.value[0],nt)

plt.figure(1)  # plot results
plt.plot(tm, x1.value, "k-", label=r"$x_1$")
plt.plot(tm, x2.value, "b-", label=r"$x_2$")
plt.plot(tm, x3.value, "r--", label=r"$x_3$")

plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.show()
```

I am trying to get used to Gekko as an optimization tool for some kinetic data. Therefore, I tried to implement a simple ode system based on an example of the Gekko website. Nevertheless, it never found the global maximum unless I force the derivative to be `dx2/dt>0` to get the right maximum. This is somewhat unsatisfying, as I would expect a solver to find the maximum of component `x2` just by asking to find the Maximum via `m.Maximize(x2)` for such a simple system. Is there any setting I did wrong or is my solution badly proposed? Thanks for helping.

The result: shows clearly that the maximum is not found...

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unconstrained objective (without the constraint `dx2dt>=0`) is `10416.8` while the objective with the constraint is `9236.4` (worse). Additional constraints never improve the optimization result but can make the objective worse for convex optimization problems such as this one.

```py
m.Equation(x2.dt() >= 0)
```

[image]

Here is the code that shows the results of adding the constraint:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()  # initialize gekko

nt=200
m.time = np.linspace(0,1,nt)
# Variables
x1 = m.Var(value=20,lb=0,)
x2 = m.Var(value=0,lb=0,)
x3 = m.Var(value=0,lb=0,)

p = np.zeros(nt)  # mark final time point
p[-1] = 1.0

# optimize final time
tf = m.FV(value=0.7,lb=0.001,ub=100.0)
tf.STATUS = 1

# Equations
m.Equation(x1.dt() == -5*x1*tf)
m.Equation(x2.dt() == (5* x1 - 0.5*x2)*tf)
m.Equation(x3.dt() == 0.5*x2*tf)

#Minifunc
#m.Minimize(tf)
m.Maximize(x2)

#options
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.SOLVER = 1 #APOPT optimizer
m.options.RTOL = 1E-8
m.options.OTOL = 1E-8
m.options.NODES = 5
m.solve(disp=True,debug=1)

plt.figure(1)
tm = np.linspace(0,tf.value[0],nt)
plt.plot(tm, x2.value, "b:", label=r"$x_2$ Optimal")

# add constraint
m.Equation(x2.dt() >= 0)
m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
m.solve(disp=True,debug=1)

tm = np.linspace(0,tf.value[0],nt)
plt.plot(tm, x2.value, "r--", label=r"$x_2$ Constrained")
plt.legend(loc="best"); plt.xlabel("Time"); plt.ylabel("Value")

print('Final Time: ' + str(tf.value[0]))

plt.figure(2)  # plot results
plt.plot(tm, x1.value, "k-", label=r"$x_1$")
plt.plot(tm, x2.value, "b-", label=r"$x_2$")
plt.plot(tm, x3.value, "r--", label=r"$x_3$")

plt.legend(loc="best"); plt.xlabel("Time"); plt.ylabel("Value")

plt.show()
```

The current objective statement is to maximize the value of `x2` everywhere.

```py
m.Maximize(x2)
```

Even though there is a maximum part-way through the simulation, the final objective is the summation of all the `x2` values. Make the following changes to maximize only the final `x2` point.

```py
p = np.zeros(nt)  # mark final time point
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(p)

m.Maximize(x2*final)
```

[image: Maximize Final Point]

The optimal solution is now just the final point for `x2` that is **15.485**.